# using xslt to pass node value as an argument to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I am new to this so I don't know whether this approach is the correct way to pass an argument. Please help me correct this or suggest another way to do this. I want to pass a node value from the xslt to a javascript function.

This is my XML file :

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sample.xsl"?>
   <One>
       <Two>
           HelloWorld
       </Two>
   </One>
```

This is the xslt file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<xsl:variable name="url" select="One/Two"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <script>
        function Myclick(vara)
        {
            alert(vara);            
        }
    </script>
    <xsl:for-each select="One">
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                http://www.google.com
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="onClick">                      
                alert($url);
                Myclick($url);
            </xsl:attribute>            
            <xsl:value-of select="Two"/>
        </a>
    </xsl:for-each>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: yes. It does not pass the value into the function.

Comment: Can you share the output rendered?

Comment: The output is just an anchor saying HelloWorld. The idea is when I click this link the alert box should pop and then go on to the href given. But it just goes on to open google which is the href given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <xsl:variable name="url" select="One/Two"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <script>
                    function Myclick(a)
                    {
                        var href = a.getAttribute('href');
                        alert(href);
                        location.href= href;
                    }
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="One">
                    <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                            http://www.google.com
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="onClick">
                            javascript:Myclick(this); return false;
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Two"/>
                    </a>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I want to pass a value of the xml document into the javascript. How can I modify this to do that ? ex: I want to pass the value of Two of the xml document, i.e HelloWorld into the javascript.

Comment: I have edited the code so no you get an alert and then you are redirected to google. notice that I have removed the href attribute.

Comment: What exactly is passed to the js function ? As in what does 'this' pass ?

Comment: this is the 'a' tag from the dom that is being clicked on. notice that I have improved the xslt so it is more generic now. and I have also returned the href attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Your XSLT code is not calling any Javascript function; it is merely generating HTML.

Do you know what HTML you want to generate? If so, tell us, and we can help you generate it. If not, you shouldn't be trying to write XSLT code - never start writing a program (in any language) until you know what output you want it to produce.